# How to replace 31 css classes with just one

Tags: css

I have 31 icons of a calendar one for each day of the month and my css looks not as good as I would like. Right now I've:

```
.icon-agenda.day-1, .icon-agenda.day-1:before{
    background: url(../images/tiles/agenda/1.png) no-repeat;
}

.icon-agenda.day-2, .icon-agenda.day-2:before{
    background: url(../images/tiles/agenda/2.png) no-repeat;
}

.icon-agenda.day-3, .icon-agenda.day-3:before{
    background: url(../images/tiles/agenda/3.png) no-repeat;
}

.icon-agenda.day-4, .icon-agenda.day-4:before{
    background: url(../images/tiles/agenda/4.png) no-repeat;
}

...
.icon-agenda.day-31, .icon-agenda.day-31:before{
    background: url(../images/tiles/agenda/31.png) no-repeat;
}
```

I would like to replace the above code with something more simple like

```
.icon-agenda.day-xxx, .icon-agenda.day-xxx:before{
    background: url(../images/tiles/agenda/xxx.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Can I do something like this in CSS?

Comment: You might want to look into something like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [Less](http://lesscss.org/). CSS doesn't have this type of functionality natively.

Comment: only in CSS, or can use PHP, Java-Script, etc??

Comment: Have you considered inline style instead (
`<i style="background-image:url(1.png)"></i>`)? This way you will only have one simple css rule.

Comment: @SimoneNigro I can use javascript.

Comment: @kornieff At this point I don't want to pollute the html with code that can be done in a separate css file.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst even using sass or less the result css isn't the same?

Comment: @PedroRainho, what you're doing is the same as making bunch of image tags and leaving the src values blank and trying to do it in css somehow. Inline style would be a lot cleaner and with a bit better performance. Anyway, it's your pain. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way *(yet)* to do this in native CSS. You could use a preprocessor like LESS, but that would generate the same output, only with the added hassle of compiling it, so your current method is the most optimal one as far as this layout goes.

One possible optimization could be to create an entire sprite from all of the images, set it as a `background-image` for all items with 1 selector like `[class*=".icon-agenda.day-"], [class*=".icon-agenda.day-"]:before`, and alter the `background-position` of the separate elements. This would save you requests meaning a faster page load.

As per your comment about using JavaScript, here's a solution that will add an extra `<style>` tag to the `<head>` of the page with your CSS:

```
var styl = document.createElement('style');
for (var i=1; i<=31; i++)
    styl.innerHTML += '.icon-agenda.day-'+i+',.icon-agenda.day-'+i+':before{background:url(../images/tiles/agenda/'+i+'.png) no-repeat}';
document.head.appendChild(styl);
```

Comment: about the sprite I've thought about it but if I have a page that uses the image with just 1kb for instante, why should I have a image that has 1kb*31 = 31kb? The only optimization that I can think is cache the image once.

Comment: @PedroRainho 31 Small requests take longer to complete than 1 bigger request due to less lookup and waiting time per image opposed to looking up and waiting 31 times. Also, look into online image optimization services like [Compressor.io](https://compressor.io/compress) which can reduce the image size of the sprite so it's even smaller than if you were to optimize the 31 images separately.

Answer (score 0):

At some point in the future, you will be able to do

```
background-image: attr(data-png url);
```

which would take the URL from the `data-png` attribute of each element.

Right now it only works with the `content` CSS property.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr.